# TensorFlow in Python 3.12

Tags: python, sql, database, machine-learning, debugging

I’m trying to import data into SQL through Python, and I'm using pyodbc and TensorFlow in Python 3.12, but TensorFlow doesn’t work. I can’t use python 3.11 because pyodbc isn’t compatible with it.

I tried using `pip install tensorflow`, and I got this error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none) 
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

How do I fix this while staying in Python 3.12?

Comment: If you mean [this pyodbc](https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/), it only requires [Python 3.8+](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/blob/bc5b7c6f50f71aa776f881fafce95328338ed35e/pyproject.toml#L5).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that TensorFlow is now only available up to version 3.11 of Python.

*[Install TensorFlow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/install)*

While I don't find any information that pyodbc isn't compatible with Python 3.11. You may use Python 3.11 and try again.

*[pyodbc](https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/)* ([PyPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Package_Index))